# a probability density algorithm that is not sensitive to the initial condition

Tags: st.statistics, probability-distributions, algorithms, machine-learning

There are many algorithms to estimate the density of probability distributions. I am looking for one that is not sensitive to the initial condition. For instance, Expectation–maximization algorithm starts by initializing the parameters theta to some random values and then it goes from there to other steps. So for different theta one might obtain two different distributions estimate. Are there algorithms that do not have this dependency? in other words, it only depends on the samples from which we are trying to estimate the density?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result obtained by a local numerical optimization solver applied to a non-convex optimization problem is sensitive to the starting value used by the optimizer. Expectation-maximization as applied to find a local optimum of a non-convex maximum likelihood estimation problem is one such example of a local optimization solver.

If you use a "rigorous" (for example, based on branch and bound) numerical global optimization solver, and the problem is solved to global optimality (which may require non-trivial run-time and maybe memory for problems with many parameters to estimate), then the optimal objective value (measure of fit being optimized), will be independent of starting value. The optimal parameter values will also be independent of starting value provided that there is a unique global optimum. In reality, problems are solved to within some specified relative or absolute tolerance gap on the objective value, and the problem is easier to 'solve", the larger the specified gap (non-dependence on starting value only then applies relative to getting some solution within the specified gap, but the solution obtained and the actual gap achieved may depend on the starting value). In contrast, a local optimization solver provides no information as to how close the solution found is in objective value to the global optimum.

BARON is one such rigorous numerical global optimization optimizer (it is not totally rigorous, given that it can still be fooled by very badly numerically behaved functions which overtax its internal precision).  The main issue with it is that run-time can be very long on some problems - that's why local optimizers are still used.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Mark. I am aware of the local optimum nature of the EM algorithm and know that a global solution is possible (but slow) for that particular method or methods like it. My question is different though. I am looking for _any_ probability estimation algorithm, using MLE or otherwise, that is only sample independent. If you are aware of something like that, would you be able to point me to an existing software ? Thanks

Comment: I don;t understand what you mean by "that is only sample independent.". Unless you have a (stupid) constant estimator, the estimate will depend on the data sample which is being fit (input to the algorithm). That is different than dependence of which local optimum id found on the starting value (of the parameters being fit) used to find it.

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear, I meant to say,only depends on the samples and nothing else.

Comment: That is essentially what global optimization does (realtive to the provided objective function and constrains) , presuming the problem is actually solved to global optimality, and presuming the parameters achieving the globally optimal objective value are unique. If the global optimum is not unique, then in some sense you have a poorly specified problem (the combination of data sample and objective function (criterion such as MLE) being optimized